# Django Rest Framework: dynamic database on POST - RelatedField or PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework, relationship, django-queryset

I'm developing RESTFul services with DRF and I have multiple databases depending on the country (see my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682216/django-rest-framework-set-database-dynamically-from-url-parameter))

I'm having a problem now with relationships, I have two models: Category and SubCategory:

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):    
    objects = CountryQuerySet.as_manager()
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column='sub_category_id')
    name = models.TextField()
    female_items_in_category = models.BooleanField()
    male_items_in_category = models.BooleanField()
    kids_items_in_category = models.BooleanField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = Constants().SUBCATEGORY
```

And the serializer is:

```
class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  

    category = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.using('es').all())

    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = ('id', 'name','female_items_in_category','male_items_in_category','kids_items_in_category','category')
```

If I don't set the queryset with the proper country it fails, because it doesn't know where to get the category.

**Here the problem**

I already set the country in the serializer context (in the ModelViewSet):

```
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {Constants().COUNTRY: self.kwargs.get(Constants().COUNTRY)}
```

But I can not find the proper way to get the self.context.get(Constants().COUNTRY) in the serializer.

Do you any have an idea to solve this?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution to my problem: I overwrite the method get_fields in the serializer:

```
    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = super(SubCategorySerializer, self).get_fields()
        country = self.context.get(Constants().COUNTRY)
        qs = Category.objects.using(country).all()
        fields['category'].queryset = qs
        return fields
```

And that works!